# How to compare two variables from a java class in jess and execute a rule?

Tags: java, jess

I'm beginner in Jess. I'm trying to compare two variables from a Java class in Jess and trying to execute a rule.

I have imported `cTNumber` and `measuredCurrent` (both are integer)form a java class called `CurrentSignal`. Similarly imported `vTNumber`and `measuredVoltage` form a java class `DERSignal`. Now I want to make a rule such that if `cTNumber` is equal to `vTNumber` then multiply `measuredCurrent` and `measuredVoltage` (Both are double) for calculating power.

I'm trying in this way....

```
(import signals.*)
(deftemplate CurrentSignal (declare (from-class CurrentSignal)))
(deftemplate DERSignal (declare (from-class DERSignal)))

(defglobal ?*CTnumber* = 0)
(defglobal ?*VTnumber* = 0)
(defglobal ?*VTnumberDER* = 0)

(defglobal ?*measuredCurrent* = 0)
(defglobal ?*measuredVoltage* = 0)
(defglobal ?*measuredVoltageDER* = 0)


(defrule Get-CT-Number

   (CurrentSignal (cTNumber ?m)) 
   (CurrentSignal (measuredCurrent ?c))

=>
    (bind ?*measuredCurrent* ?c)
      (printout t "Measured Current : " ?*measuredCurrent*" Amps"crlf)
    (bind ?*CTnumber* ?m)
      (printout t ?*CTnumber* crlf)
)


(defrule Get-DER-Number

   (DERSignal (vTNumber ?o)) 
   (DERSignal (measuredVoltage ?V))

=>
     (bind ?*measuredVoltageDER* ?V)
       (printout t "Measured Voltage : " ?*measuredVoltageDER* " V" crlf)
    (bind ?*VTnumberDER* ?o)
       (printout t ?*VTnumberDER* crlf)
)


(defrule Power-Calculation-DER-signal

    "Power calculation of DER Bay"

    (test (= ?*CTnumber* ?*VTnumberDER* ))
    =>

  (printout t "Total Generation : " (* ?*measuredCurrent* ?*measuredVoltageDER*) crlf)
)
```

But the Total Generation is showing 0. But I tried calculating in Java and it's showing a number. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it all in a single rule?

```
(defrule Power-Calculation-DER-signal
  (CurrentSignal (cTNumber ?m)(measuredCurrent ?c))
  (DERSignal {vTNumber == ?m} (measuredVoltage ?V))
=>
  (printout t "Total Generation : " (* ?c ?V) crlf)
)
```

Using globals the way you did is not a good idea. A change does not affect rules. See the Jess manual on globals.

**Added later**

```
(reset)
(deftemplate CurrentSignal (slot cTNumber)(slot measuredCurrent))
(deftemplate DERSignal (slot vTNumber)(slot measuredVoltage))
(assert (CurrentSignal (cTNumber 12)(measuredCurrent 10)))
(assert (DERSignal (vTNumber 12) (measuredVoltage 13)))

(defrule Power-Calculation-DER-signal
  (CurrentSignal (cTNumber ?m)(measuredCurrent ?c))
  (DERSignal {vTNumber == ?m} (measuredVoltage ?V))
=>
  (printout t "Total Generation : " (* ?c ?V) crlf)
)
(run)

Jess> (batch voltage.clp )
Total Generation : 130
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I tried the way you suggested but somehow it's not firing the rule(not printing anything). Is there any other way to compare these variables?

Comment: The you must have some other fly in the ointment. See the self-contained Jess code I've added to my answer.